# Is this use of tables proper, in webpage layout?

Tags: css, w3c

I understand table are used to display data that is suited to a table format.  Something that occurs to me is forum websites.  They largely seem to use tables to display the list of forums, thread count, last post, etc.  Is this a justifiable use of table?

For example ruby-forum.com

Answer (score 1):

I would say so, the [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1):

> The HTML table model allows authors to
>   arrange data -- text, preformatted
>   text, images, links, forms, form
>   fields, other tables, etc. -- into
>   rows and columns of cells.

This is definitely data, and belongs in a table format.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is if it contains more than two columns, use a table. Two column designs (like the Table of Contents here: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/) are very feasible with floats, and work quite well.

Anything more than two will be basically impossible to create. Look at a common forum layout (like VBulletin, phpBB, etc.), and you can see *why* a table is used.

Yes, it is.